# Is there a way to get any console messages from Edge browser either through a remote debugging protocol or by starting it via the command line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, remote-debugging, microsoft-edge, console.log

I'm using Chrome's remote debugging protocol to get console messages when loading Chrome up for a site.

But I wondered if there's a way to script Edge to do the same?

*I know I can look in the console itself, or add some script to the page to do this, but I'm trying to do it from an external point of view.*

*E.g. With a script to automatically load up the Edge browser, navigate to a page, and have it log any console messages it find to a file somewhere.*

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/27/introducing-edge-diagnostics-adapter/#wvBAITAtjBLOoIdz.97?

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan, I'd looked at this too but it looks like it doesn't offer the Console area yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/edge-diagnostics-adapter/wiki/Supported-features-and-API

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function and send all console messages to the function which would console.log the output and send it to your server via AJAX for appending to a file.  A nodejs microservice would be quick and simple to do this with.  I've done this for a quick and dirty logging system when developing.  I try to log with a **datatime stamp, user, etc** and what the output was.

I am assuming that you do not want this long term (console logs in production is a poor idea).

Comment: Hey @splitwire, thanks but as mentioned in the question I'm looking more for an external way to do this from outside the browser/Edge itself, a bit like the remote debugging protocol in Chrome, that doesn't require any script added to the pages themselves. (Main reason for this is that I want to run this over pages I don't have access to change).

Comment: stilliard - I completely skipped over that requirement; sorry.  I wonder if you could extend console.log (I know, not a recommended thing but this seems to be a unique requirement), and inject your solution automatically on page load.  I'm not sure a better way forward.  Good luck.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the suggestion anyway. I could possibly look into proxying the responses and inject an override in at that stage you're right. But one of the pretty awesome things I get from the Chrome remote debugging protocol is any browser warnings about the page, that'd be useful to get from Edge too, not just js errors and logs from withing the page, but things like blocked scripts being run and invalid html etc.